# Медиа-запросы не работают

Tags: css, адаптивная-верстка, экран

Здравствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста, советом: пытаюсь с помощью медиа-запросов отрегулировать ширину шапки и контента, но не выходит. Мне нужно, чтобы если экран устройства менее 1024 px, поля не показывались, а шапка и контент занимали 100% экрана, на широкоэкранных мониторах чтобы шапка и контент занимали 53%, остальное, соответственно, поля. Прописывала, вроде бы, правильно:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    #main {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #header {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
}

#header {
    background-image: url(../images/header.jpg);
    width: 53%;
    height: 239px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

#main {
    width: 53%;
    min-height: 800px;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    overflow: auto;
    font-family: serif;
}
```

Проверяла неоднократно на устройствах с разрешением менее 1024 px - правила не работают, все равно появляются поля и контент с шапкой занимают 53 %, отчего получается тоненькая полоска (. Что я не так делаю? Может, медиа-запросы не в файл стилей нужно записывать? Как еще можно осуществить задумку? Пробовала также max-device-width, все равно не работает.

Comment: перенесите запросы вниз

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все заработало, не могла даже подумать, что это из-за порядка)

Comment: Может в шапку добавить meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" или initial-scale=1.0

Comment: @ПавелМельник Нет, это не то, что хочет топикстартер.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Надо поставить media после обычных, чтобы они переопределяли стандартные правила:

```
#main {
  width: 53%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { 
  #main {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Можно было бы проверить размер

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { 
  #main {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) { 
  #main {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Но такой метод правильно работает только с пикселями, если там будут другие единицы измерения, то возможны промежуточные стостояния, при которых, в зависимости от реализации, либо не применится ни один блок, либо применятся оба. Поэтому, на мой взгляд, лучше сразу делать с переопределением.

Answer (score 3):

Поскольку у вас общая часть стоит позже запроса она отрабатывает всегда, и "перетирает" условия. Нужно либо поменять порядок (как уже написали) либо сделать условие `not` для "всего остального" (аналог `else`):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { 
...
}
@media not screen and (max-width: 1024px) { 
...
}
```

Comment: Ты с not screen уверен? Что-то сомнительно, чтобы оно работало так, как требуется по вопросу.

Comment: @Qwertiy вроде как работает http://jsfiddle.net/u4xzw65a/2/

Comment: Кажется, при печати не срабатывает. Не могу понять - браузер что-то хитрит с переключением...

Comment: @Qwertiy а если вместо `screen` `all` поставить?

Comment: Похоже, что да.